# How to find the general solution using the Hermite polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, wave-equation, hermite-polynomials, hermite-normal-form

I want to solve this equation
$${\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2m})^n}\Bigr(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx} - im\omega x\Bigr) }^n\psi(x) =0$$

See more about [Hermite function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions) recursion relation
$(x-\partial) (e^{x^2/2}\partial^n e^{-x^2})=- (e^{x^2/2}\partial^{n+1} e^{-x^2})$.

Here's $\psi$ for some value of n

For $n=0$ , $\psi(x) = 0$

$n=1, \psi(x) = C e^{-\frac{m\omega  }{2\hbar}x^2}$

$n=2$
[image]
$f(x) = \psi, a = \hbar/i, b = m \omega x$
Is there a more general solution for all values of n?